# why it isn't good practice to send datatable and dataset in webservice response

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

i have received a web service which I need to integrate in to my code but the response i get for these methods is a DataTable. Please help me to understand why it is not good practice to follow.

Comment: In your title you ask IF it is a good practice. In your question you want explanation why it isn't good practice. It is unclear what you are asking

Comment: Without more details the answer is at best "maybe". If this is an internally consumed service, it might be very easy to return a data table, if it's an external service, probably not ideal. I like to separate out my contracts (request/response), from the underlying structure - which in this case I'm assuming your data table is a mirror of an actual database record. In a pinch that's a fast way to do it though

Comment: you should not use dataTable or DataSet for sending the response because generally webservices are created to use globally, so if you will use dataTable or DataSet then other platform except then the .net will not be able to use your webservice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short the main reason why it should be bad practice to return a data-table or data-set on a web service is because generally a web service can be consumed by multiple sources(be it internally or externally), if you for instance return a data-table to an ajax call you will sit with a heap of larger problems as the data-table objects generally contains extra data variables which is just extra bandwidth to a call if you could already have received the final objects.

Methods(if it is an internal call) which returns data-tables or even data-sets should be moved into the database layer of an application to be called when the business layer wants to build the final objects to return back to the Interface layer to send into a response or to do something with it.

It is generally best to already return the Structured list of strongly typed objects or dynamics(if you send scale-able types of data) when constructing a response for a web service.